# NodeJS/Puppeteer - Help clicking element

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I know is not my first question for this problem, but I'm really stuck

I need to click at the third div with class "menu-lateral-contraido-container" (lista_chamados), div to="/main/listachamado/":

```
                         <div class="menu-lateral-contraido-container">
                            <div class="menu-lateral-contraido-sub-container" title="Abertura de Chamado" draggable="true" style="opacity: 1;">
                               <div to="/main/abrechamadofone/" class="route-redirect-box">
                                  <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-container cor-tema-topo-fundo ">
                                     <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-icon"><i class="ellevo-icons">chamado_fone</i></div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-lateral-contraido-sub-container" title="Lista de Tarefas" draggable="true" style="opacity: 1;">
                               <div to="/main/listatarefa/" class="route-redirect-box">
                                  <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-container cor-tema-topo-fundo ">
                                     <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-icon"><i class="ellevo-icons">lista_tarefa</i></div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-lateral-contraido-sub-container" title="Lista de Chamados" draggable="true" style="opacity: 1;">
                               <div to="/main/listachamado/" class="route-redirect-box">
                                  <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-container cor-tema-topo-fundo ">
                                     <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-icon"><i class="ellevo-icons">lista_chamado</i></div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-lateral-contraido-sub-container" title="Abertura de Tarefa" draggable="true" style="opacity: 1;">
                               <div to="/main/aberturatarefa/" class="route-redirect-box">
                                  <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-container cor-tema-topo-fundo ">
                                     <div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-icon"><i class="ellevo-icons">abertura_tarefa</i></div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
```

Since they all have the same class and no id, I tried to click by title

```
//Error: No node found for selector: div[title="Lista de Chamados"]
await page.click('div[title="Lista de Chamados"]');
```

The problem then was I had to wait for DOM to load or use page.evaluate, but none of them works

```
//FAZ LOGIN:
await page.click('#login'),

await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

//await page.click('div[title="Lista de Tarefas"]'); //Error: No node found for selector: div[title="Lista de Tarefas"]

const seletor = 'div[title="Lista de Chamados"]';
const botao = await page.$(seletor);
console.log(botao); //null
botao.click();

const botao = await page.evaluate( () => {
    let b = document.querySelector('div[title="Lista de Chamados"]');
    console.log('in>>> ' + b); // b and b[0] are NULL
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `await page.click('[to="/main/listachamado/"]')`?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did: Error: No node found for selector: [to="/main/listachamado/"]

Comment: Just to make sure, are you trying to click `div[to="/main/listachamado/"]` or its parent element `div[title="Lista de Chamados"]`?

Comment: so, i don't know really what shoul I click... I tried to figure what element had a click function attached to it through devtools, but didn't succeed

Comment: When you log the `page.content()`, are you receiving the HTML you are expecting?

Comment: no, is not the same html I took from dev tools... https://jsfiddle.net/t6aub1mf/

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know what happened when you run this code. I'll change according to your error log. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are clicking the element even before it's loaded properly. Let's use `waitFor` function to wait for the element even before we try to do anything. Also just to be sure, we need to wait for the whole page is loaded, not only `dom`.

```
// wait for navigation and click
await Promise.all(
  page.click("#login"),

  // wait till the browsers spinner stops spinning
  page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" })
);
const selector = `div[title="Lista de Chamados"]`;

// wait for the selector to appear (maybe due to ajax etc)
await page.waitFor(selector);
await page.$(seletor);
```